# "Off with his head!" What is the structure of this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

"Off with his head". That is 'chop off his head'. 
I saw it in 'Alice's Adventures in Wonderland'. The Queen was in a furious passion, and went stamping about, and shouting 'off with his head!' or 'off with her head!'

So,'off with his head' is 'chop off his head'. If so why 'with'? '(Chop) off his head' does not have 'with'. The structure of this sentence is somewhat confusing me(non-native). Is 'Off' a verb or a adverb? Very confusing. If the Queen had said 'chop off his head!', it would easy for me to understand the structure of the sentence. but why 'off with his head?'

So, first, is 'Off' a verb or a adverb? Does 'off' mean 'chop off' or 'cut off'? 
Second, This 'Chop off his head' does not have 'with', but why 'off with his head' does have 'with'?

Comment: Think of it as having a similar structure to "*on with the show*". The structure is *(something) with (noun)*, where the 'something' looks like a preposition but acts like a verb.

Comment: It's a [phrase](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/263700.html), not a sentence, but conveys the same meaning as the sentence you mentioned.

Comment: "off" can be a verb as in "He **offed** him," to mean, "He killed him," or imperatively, "**Off** and don't come back!" In your sense, however, it's a phrase and not a sentence. In both of your instances, "off" is an adverb and not a "preposition", so this may be where your confusion lies.

Comment: This is a great learner's question. _Up with the vote button!_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare *Off with you!* which is a way of saying "Scram!"  That is, an imperative construction that means "Be off!" or "Get out of here!"

*Off with his head!* is a way of saying "Cut his head off!" or in long-winded paraphrase, "Make it so his head is off!"

The most difficult thing to explain here is the preposition **with**. I would venture to say it means "with respect to", or "regarding".  The object of *with* can be something regarded.

> What's up with that?